# eclipse компилирует, но не выдает результат

Tags: c++, eclipse

сборка проходит успешно, но не выдает результат программы, запускаю хеллоу ворлд, но ничего не выводится[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы её запустили или только собрали? eclipse не компилирует, компилирует g++, судя по скрину

Comment: только собрал, на запуск не реагирует

Comment: попробовал запустить через run as-> local application
выдает ошибку "launch failed. binary not found"

Comment: Сам не пользовался этой IDE, но похоже, что No launch configurations означает, что не настроена конфигурация для запуска. Поэтому и `#include` подчёркивает. Сделайте это или почитайте туториал в документации IDE, как там запустить минимальный пример